# Me gustaría saber si mi programa está bien y cómo mejorarlo (trata de decir los divisores de un número)

Tags: java

Se trata de sacar por consola los divisores de un número dado por el usuario. Me gustaría que al principio mostrara un mensaje que dijese: Los divisores de num son: ... Pero no sé dónde añadirlo para que no se repita todas las veces que dura el bucle

```
Scanner tec = new Scanner (System.in);

int num;
int i;
System.out.println("Introduce a positive number");
num = tec.nextInt();
    do {

        for (i = 1;i<=num;i++) 
        {
            if (num % i == 0) 
            {
            
                System.out.print(i + " ");

            }
        }
    }while (num > 0);
        System.out.println("You have introduced a wrong value");
```

Comment: El mensaje se puede imprimir antes de iniciar el ciclo, antes del do.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes como dice Jack El Destripador xD:

- Veo dos posibles formas de resolver:

a) Puedes en primer lugar solicitar el número sobre el cual quieres mostrar tus divisores. Comprobaría además si es verdad que el usuario ha introducido un número > 0.

Una vez solicitado el número y antes del bucle, muestras por pantalla el mensaje "The dividers of num  are":

y a continuación únicamente utilizaría el bucle for, no le encuentro sentido al ducle do-while. Si el número no es mejor que 0 se va a ejecutar el bucle for, por eso es mejor en todo caso que hagas lo siguiente si quieres usar el bucle do-while:

```
Scanner tec = new Scanner (System.in);

int num;
int i;
System.out.println("Introduce a positive number");
do {
   num = tec.nextInt();
   if (num < 0) System.out.println("You have introduced a wrong value");
} while (num > 0);

// Si llegas aquí entonces sabes que el num > 0
// y entras en el for

System.out.println("The dividers of num are: ");
for (i = 1;i<=num;i++) {
   if (num % i == 0) {
      System.out.print(i + " ");
   }
}
```

También podrías usar listas o colecciones, e ir acumulando el resultado para luego mostrarlo, pero con eso te valdría, si no tienes ninguna especiación adicional:

Espero te sirva de ayuda!

Comment: Mil gracias Santiago, me ha servido mucho aunque al final lo he hecho distinto
Scanner tec = new Scanner (System.in);
long num;
int i;
System.out.println("Introduce a positive number and I will show you the divisors of it");
 do {
 num = tec.nextInt();
 System.out.println("The divisors of " + num + " are:");
  for (i = 1;i<=num;i++) 
  {
  if (num % i == 0) 
  {
  System.out.print(i + " ");
  }
  }
}while (num > 0 && i <= num);
  if (num < 0) {
   System.out.println("You have introduced a wrong value");
  } else {
   System.out.println("\nThank you for participating"); 
  }

Comment: @Alejandro la solución que planteas está mal, ten en cuenta en un bucle ``do while`` siempre se va ejecutar por lo menos una vez las sentencias de código entre llaves, entonces lo mejor es hacerlo como te plantean en la solución.